# Customise Solution List in Team Explorer Home Page (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

I am using TFS with Visual Studio 2015. On the Team Explorer Home window it lists solutions from my current workspace. This is a really handy place to open solutions from - however the solutions listed seem to be just a random selection from the workspace. It doesn't even list my recently opened solutions. Is there any way to customise this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be achieved.

However there is a workaround, after checking this option " Open Source Control Explorer to the most recent folder" in Tools→Options→ VSTFS, it will remember your last TFS tree selection and jump the very same branch and sub-folder again.